# Add Polygon Attributes to Points error QGIS

Tags: qgis, saga

I am trying to run the **Add Polygon Attributes to Points** algorithm from the Processing Toolbox in QGIS but I run into an error. All my points are either inside the polygon or exactly on the border. I have a feeling that those points exactly on the border might not belong to a polygon. Any suggestions or alternatives?

This is the error message:

[image: error message]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Join attribute by location to the join the polygon's attribute to the points. You can access the tool from `Vector -> Data Management Tools -> Join attribute by location`.

[image]

In this case you can confirm whether the points are really located inside the polygons or not. And if they located inside or snapped to the polygon correctly, the attribute of the polygon will be transferred to the point.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this issue by using multipart to singleparts (vector geometry tools) on my points first.