# Add polygon attributes to points fails to create layer

Tags: qgis, point, saga

I'm trying to add polygon attributes to a point file with a lot (~370,000) of points in QGIS v3.0.0.  I first tried using the point sampling tool, which I've used with success pulling the values from raster files, but this became unresponsive and remained so for several hours.

A search pointed me to the Saga **add polygon attributes to points** from the processing toolbox, and reported it to be much faster than **join attributes by location** see this post by @Underdark [link](https://anitagraser.com/2013/10/02/add-polygon-attributes-to-points-vs-join-attributes-by-location/).  This completed quickly but failed to create or add a layer.  I got a similar error as @Tali in this [question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/228909/add-polygon-attributes-to-points-error-qgis).  I followed the **multipart to singlepart** suggestion, but to no effect- my polygons were all initially single part features.  I also ran **v.build.check** to see if I had any other topological errors in my polygon file, but found none.

The error message I get is:
[image: error message]

I can do other processing tasks with the point layer, and tried both in and out of edit mode.  The tool works fine with the same polygon layer and a much smaller point files (~400 pts), but still failed when I used a ~200k point subset.  I've tried re-running with the output set to save as both as shapefile and as geopackage, but get the same result. 
I converted both my point and region files to geopackages and tried again, with the same error. I also tried in a blank map document with only the two files and get the same error.

Any ideas on how to resolve the error with the **add polygon attributes to points**, or an alternate tool that could accomplish the same thing in a reasonable amount of time?

Comment: Have you tried saving the output to disk instead of as a temporary layer?

Comment: Any chance you could share your data?

Comment: @Joseph I've tried saving output to disk in both geopackage and shapefile formats.

Comment: @ndawson I posted the files to dropbox and edited the question to add the link.  Data converted to geopackage for transfer and tested.  I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: Thanks. Using QGIS 3.0, the "Join attributes by location" tool worked fine for me (took 16 seconds).

Comment: "Join attributes by location" worked for me as well.  Thank you @ndawson.  I edited the post to take down the data